# XCode - How to include React Native libraries in Share Extension?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I'm attempting to create a Share Extension in a React Native application.

At compilation time, I'm running into the following error:

[image: textual error below]

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
"_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
Linker command failed with exit code 1
(use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm interpreting this error as *the Share Extension is unable to find/link the associated libraries*.

I've attempted to define the libraries in the Share Extension's:

- `General` -> `Frameworks and Libraries`
- `Build Settings` -> `Search Paths` -> `Library Search Paths`

The project here: https://github.com/Meandmybadself/react-native-share-starter

**Versions**

- `XCode`: 11.3.1
- `Podfile iOS version`: `11.0`
- `react-native`: 0.63.4